# Firebase con Volley alternativo, ¿cómo funcionan los listeners y el snapshot? ¿qué ocurre si sobrepaso un límite del plan «free» de Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-volley

En mi App estoy creando la posibilidad de mostrar datos según el siguiente criterio:

1. Buscar primero en Real Time Database de Firebase
2. Si no encuentra nada en Firebase, buscar en mi servicio REST mediante Volley
3. En cualquiera de los dos casos mostrar los datos obtenidos

Esta es la parte del código que maneja ambos procesos:

#### Buscar datos en Firebase:

```
    final String refPath = "liturgia/breviario/tercia/" + strFechaHoy;

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(refPath);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                mBreviario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Breviario.class);
                showData();
            }else{
                launchVolley();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mTextView.setText(databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```

#### Buscar datos en mi REST con Volley

```
public void launchVolley() {
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, URL_TERCIA + strFechaHoy, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    mBreviario = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response), Breviario.class);
                    showData();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyErrorHelper errorVolley = new VolleyErrorHelper();
                    String sError = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);
                    mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(sError));
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
    );

    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

El código funciona bien, cuando no encuentra datos en Firebase los busca en el REST y los muestra.

Mi duda es en la parte de Firebase:

- Yo hago una llamada desde ahí a `showData` sin más. No cierro nada, no termino nada, simplemente asigno el valor de `dataSnapshot` a mi modelo y en `showData` me obtiene todo correctamente, incluso si modifico algún dato en Firebase lo actualiza en la App. ¿Es correcto mi código o debo hacer algo más en cuanto al snapshot?
- Si sobrepaso alguno de los límites de Firebase: conexiones concurrentes, cantidad de datos usados, etc. ¿Mi código actual llamará a `launcVolley` o la App fallará inesperadamente.

NOTA:

El sentido de usar Firebase y Volley como alternativa es que estoy intentando dar persistencia a mi App. Dado que no he tenido tiempo de una migración adecuada del modelo de datos a Firebase y no sé si el consumo de datos de la App sobrepase los límites del plan gratuito de Firebase, estoy siguiendo esta lógica a modo de prueba.

Answer (score 2):

Excelente pregunta A. Cedano !! Estuve investigando un rato sobre tu inquietud por que realmente esta muy buena tu idea !

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, en la documentacion de errores de Firebase `onFailure()` solo arroja los siguientes

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/handle-errors

Como podras ver no existe ningun error sobre las conexiones simultaneas, despues de indagar un poco mas di con la respuesta de que no existe forma de saber mediante una excepcion cuando las conexiones simultaneas exceden el limite del plan free, por lo tanto, cada conexion simultanea nueva que este por encima de lo exedido va a pasar a una cola de espera para poder ejecutar la query de tu referencia que entra al `onDataSnapshot()` , esto quiere decir que tu `launchVolley()` nunca va a ser ejecutado si se exceden estas conexiones simultaneas ya que no se va a ejecutar el `onDataSnapshot()`.

Bien, con respecto a la primer pregunta si, esta bien que agarres la data, la busques y luego uses `showData()` para mostrarla, al fin y al cabo , seria igual que poner ese codigo dentro del `onDataChange()` recuerda que al ser asyncrono debes mostrar la data siempre luego de llamar datos en esa referencia.

Ahora en mi opinion personal , yo creo que esta hecho asi al proposito, por que imaginate si se pudiera saber cuando el servicio ya excedio los limites podriamos hacer algo como esto para pasar a otro backend y esperar el cooldown de los limites de Firebase, y despues volver a usar su servicio gratis de por vida, yo creo que si esto fuera posible , no existirian los planes que ellos ofrecen.

Estoy investigando mas sobre el tema, voy a ir actualizando este post con mas info, un saludo !

Comment: Gracias Gastón. Leyéndote me doy cuenta de que no se me había ocurrido la posibilidad de verificar el estado de mi plan free. ¿Seguro que no se puede? Aunque es razonable (en parte) por lo mismo que dices. Sin embargo, supongamos que puedo suscribirme a un plan de pago pero limitado y quiero alternarlo con `Volley` cuando llegue al límite de mi plan. Es una posibilidad que ellos deberían contemplar. Hay que investigar un poco más sobre el tema...

Comment: si, puedes limitar cualquier proyecto de Firebase para que trabaje como tu quieras, puedes leer un poquito mas aqui (ingles) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324299/is-there-a-way-to-limit-firebases-blaze-plan   , la persona que responde ahi trabaja en Firebase

Comment: Todos los errores que tengas, deberia arrojarlos el onCancelled() , encontre pocas preguntas apuntando a este tema, y pocas de estas son respondidas, estoy seguro que esta diseñado asi para evitar usar servicios de terceros para alternarlos con su servicio, es como si usara un auto hasta que se le acabe la gasolina, lo deje estacionado hasta que alguien le cargue mas (mientras uso otro) y luego lo vuelvo a usar cuando este este de nuevo con gasolina

Comment: hay algo que se llama sharding, que es expandir tu base de datos creando nuevas instancias , esto en firebase es posible ! y es posible teniendo el plan blaze. Eh usado esto de expandir las base de datos para tener distintos servidores , es muy bueno y te aconsejo que hagas esto para no usar volley https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding?hl=es-419

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar los enlaces que me has pasado en cuanto pueda. Me falta dar una respuesta adecuada a esta situación antes de lanzar una nueva versión de la App con capacidad de persistencia. La verdad es que `Firebase` es una maravilla pero a veces el presupuesto no da para tanto, por eso busco alternativas para ir probando. No sé qué consumo tendrá la App, pero la tendencia es que crezca su uso y más cuando tenga persistencia de datos.

Comment: Eh trabajado en una empresa donde usabamos Firebase y pagabamos por el plan por uso (Blaze) , con una base de mas de 5000 usuarios y mas de 200 activos al dia no pagabamos mucho, no te quiero mentir por que la verdad estos numeros los conocia mi jefe, pero un dia hablabamos sobre los precios y como podria afectar una mala estructura en Firebase a los mismos y me comento que no era un precio para preocuparse.

Comment: Mi App maneja datos JSON, archivos pequeños de pocos KB, es contenido en muchas partes repetitivo por lo que pienso organizarlo de forma que se pueda reutilizar sin tener que leer todos los nodos, etc. (`firestore` tiene un tipo de campo `reference` que parece interesante en ese sentido aunque me bloquée intentando mapear sub-clases en base a ese tipo de campo, bueno ese es otro tema). El plan blaze me parece interesante pero ignoro qué cantidad de personas usarán la App al día. El uso será solamente para leer contenido, ellos no van a modificar, borrar o actualizar nada, pero la App ...

Comment: ... ofrecería unos 10 o más tipos de contenido nuevos cada día muchos de los cuales son contenidos fijos que podrían traerse sin tener que repetirlos (como se hace con los `JOIN` en las bases de datos). No sé estoy estudiando todo eso porque tampoco es que Firebase funcione como las BD. Incluso parece que hay  ciertas diferencias entre Firestore y Real Time Database. Lo cierto es que eso de que cambias algo y se refleja de inmediato en el contenido de la App es remarcable. No lo había visto funcionando pero me encantó cuando lo probé en mi App.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89399/discussion-between-gaston-saillen-and-a-cedano).