# Como gestionar la asincronia de Firebase en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

estoy haciendo una aplicación que me devuelva las tareas de un usuario. Para ello, tengo una base de datos en Firebase en cual tengo dos tablas: **tabla_usuarios** y **tabla_tarea**.

En la **tabla_tareas**, tengo multiples tareas donde cada una de las tareas tiene un identificador de usuario para saber a que usuario pertenece esta tarea entre otros parametros.

```
"256209ca-2d14-4ab1-b59c-dc7de574d365" : {
  "aprobada" : false,
  "descripcion" : "soy una tarea",
  "fec_Fin" : "11/11/2011",
  "fec_Ini" : "11/11/2011",
  "fec_Resuelta" : "",
  "finalizada" : false,
  "id_Grupo" : "bb921525-cffe-4b2b-82ad-2e5dd54f2a54",
  "id_Tarea" : "256209ca-2d14-4ab1-b59c-dc7de574d365",
  "id_Usuario" : "LtJz9QxtqVVb2nRsNYkcFF5gq3c2",
  "nombre" : "tarea"
```

Mientras que en el usuario tengo un campo que me indica separado por comas (",") que tareas tiene asignadas

```
"LtJz9QxtqVVb2nRsNYkcFF5gq3c2" : {
  "apellido" : "user",
  "email_Usuario" : "usuario@gmail.com",
  "gestor" : false,
  "id_Grupo" : "bb921525-cffe-4b2b-82ad-2e5dd54f2a54",
  "id_Tarea" : "199322fd-4fff-4c96-958d-09c809eb19d3,256209ca-2d14-4ab1-b59c-dc7de574d365,6841a9ef-938d-4e79-b069-2cff48037800",
  "id_Usuario" : "LtJz9QxtqVVb2nRsNYkcFF5gq3c2",
  "nombre_Usuario" : "usuario"
```

Cuando se lanza mi activity hago lo siguiente:

En un primer lugar, desde el **onCreate** llamo a un método que accede a mi **tabla_usuario** para obtener los identificadores de las tareas que este usuario tiene asignadas.

```
private String retrieveMisTareas(){
    tablaUsuarios = mFirebaseDB.getReference("Tbl_Usuario").child(uid);
    tareas.clear();
    tablaUsuarios.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);

            //Busqueda de las tareas asignadas a un usuario
            mistareas = mistareas + usuario.getId_Tarea();
            readFromDB(tratamientoTareas(mistareas));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    return mistareas;
}
```

Una vez que el metodo se completa y tengo un String con los valores de las tareas asignadas, separo ese String en un List para poder recorrerlo.

```
private List tratamientoTareas(String mistareas){

    String [] stringTareas = mistareas.split(",");

    List<String> tareas = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringTareas));

    return tareas;
}
```

Este retorna un List que paso por parametro al metodo que me lee de Firebase las tareas asignadas con la instrucción del metodo **retrieveMisTareas()**

```
readFromDB(tratamientoTareas(mistareas));
```

Este metodo recorre el List obtenido para acceder a los childs de la tabla_tareas y retornar solo aquellas que tiene el usuario asignadas

```
private void readFromDB(List idtareas){

    for (int i = 0; i < idtareas.size() ; i++) {
        tablaTareas = mFirebaseDB.getReference("Tbl_Tarea").child((String) idtareas.get(i));

        tablaTareas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Tarea tarea = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tarea.class);
                tareas.add(tarea);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    recyclerViewSetup(tareas);
}
```

El problema es que cuando se abre la Activity, el thread de la lectura de la BBDD no ha finalizado y por tanto no se muestran por pantalla las tareas.

Alguien sabría como hacerlo correctamente? La opción de descargarme todas las tareas esta descartada.

Gracias y saludos,

Comment: Para casos parecidos al tuyo yo declaro en la clase un miembro del tipo `private`, el cual lleno dentro de la lectura de datos de Firebase  y luego llamo a un método que hace uso de ese objeto. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/235629/29967). Si observas mapeo el objeto dentro de `onDataChange` y desde ahí hago una llamada a `showData()`. Creo que eso puede servirte de ejemplo.

Comment: Buenas, si eso mismo hago yo, tengo un objeto private de tipo Tarea el cual relleno en el onDataChange usando el DataSnapshot, el problema es que el thread de el método de lectura de la BBDD acaba después del lanzamiento de la app. De hecho si espero un rato, sale la info por pantalla, pero no es instantáneo cuando debería serlo ya que es una consulta pequeña

Comment: Sí, pero deberías llamar a `recyclerViewSetup()` desde dentro de `onDataChange()` no lo estás haciendo así.

Comment: También podrías lanzar una asynctask con un ProgressDialog que se muestre mientras no has terminado las otras tareas (que informarían de su finalización levantando un flag, por ejemplo). El asynctask se lanza antes de ejecutar las funciones para obtener los datos de Firebase, mostrando un mensaje de espere por favor o algo así...