# Obtener datos de Firebase de manera sincrona

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy diseñando una clase usuarios, mi idea era implementar el constructor tal que así:

public Usuarios(String uid){
...
}

Le pasó el identificador y con el busco en la base de datos(Firestone) de Firebase los datos para rellenar mi clase, lo típico, nombre,precio... El problema es que al ejecutar la llamada a la Firestone lógicamente me lo ejecuta en otro hilo por lo que no soy capaz de capturar ningún valor para mi clase Usuario, quedándome todos los campos en null.

La idea de mi implementación es la siguiente (este método se encuentra dentro de Usuario y es llamado en el constructor):

```
private void lecturaBaseDatos(String uidL){
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Usuarios")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {                     
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            if(document.getId().equals(uidL)){
                               nombre = document.getString("Nombre");
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                               
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }

                }
            });
```

Que solución puede haber para settear bien esta sentencia nombre = document.getString("Nombre"); dentro de la clase Usuario?

Un saludo

Comment: Desde la función de escucha de Firebase puedes llenar una instancia de la clase `Usuario` con los datos que traiga el Snapshot. En la documentación hay varios ejemplos al respecto. No intentes hacer síncrono algo que es asíncrono, si es así es por motivos muy contundentes, si intentas cambiarlo podrías crear una App complicada de usar, que bloquea constantemente el hilo principal, etc, resultando en una pésima UX y en un fracaso de App que los usuarios terminarán abandonando.

Comment: Era una posibilidad que contemplé, pero al hacerlo de esa manera pierdo la referencia del objeto Usuario, por lo que no me serviría crear un usuario si luego lo pierdo y no puedo usarlo.

La idea principal es autenticarme en un layout, en el java de este layout pasarle el uid a otro layout con otro java, en este mismo crear un objeto Usuario llamando al constructor que contiene el método lecturaBaseDatos(String uidL), que expuse arriba, si en este método creo el usuario dentro de la llamada asincrona de Firebase el usuario queda perdido, no soy capaz de capturar la referencia para usarla.

Comment: No es como crees. Puedes declarar el objeto usuario como miembro de la clase o activity y llenarlo dentro del listener de Firebase, luego, si necesitas pasarlo a otra parte lo pasas desde dentro de listener de Firebase. La cuestión es que si no lo haces así, el hilo principal se bloqueará mientras la llamada a Firebase de procesa, ese es el quid de las llamadas asíncronas y es por eso motivo por el que no conviene obtener datos de manera síncrona.

Comment: Si observas [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/235629/29967), se mapea el Snapshot de Firebase a un objeto de la clase `Breviario` **dentro del listener de Firebase** y luego se llama a `showData()` **desde dentro de listener**  para que, una vez la llamada haya terminado, se muestren los datos. En `showData()` se usa el objeto `mBreviario` para mostrar los datos que fueron obtenidos desde Firebase. Es de esa forma más o menos como debes organizar el código, de lo contrario tendrás problemas de bloqueo del hilo principal, resultando en una mala UX, lo cual es grave en las Apps.

Comment: Perfecto, con ese ejemplo ya puedo encaminarlo, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés 3 formas de retornar de esta operación

Una es usando MVVM ( Model view viewmodel) en el cual retornarias un `LiveData<List<Usuario>>` el cual te quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
private LiveData<List<String>> lecturaBaseDatos(String uidL){
    MutableLiveData liveData = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Usuarios")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {                     
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<String> listaNombre = new ArrayList();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            if(document.getId().equals(uidL)){
                               nombre = document.getString("Nombre");
                               listaNombre.add(nombre);
                            }
                        }
                       liveData.setValue(listaNombre); 
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }

                }
            });
    return liveData;
}
```

Luego solo deberias observar este metodo para cuando devuelva la lista de nombres

Otra forma es usar Corutinas, implementas la libreria de Google Play Services Coroutines que te va a permitir hacer un `.await()` despues de cada `get()` en Firestore ya que cada operacion de Firestore retorna un Task, esta libreria funciona al estilo async() await, por lo que tu código quedaría algo asi

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

```
private suspend List<String> lecturaBaseDatos(String uidL){
     List<String> listaNombre = new ArrayList();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Usuarios")
            .get().await();

      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : db) {
        listaNombre.add(document.getString("Nombre")); 
      }

    return listaNombre;
}
```

La última forma es la que comenta A.Cedano en la cual usas callbacks para retornar el valor

Comment: Mejor imposible, muchas gracias por exponer los diferentes métodos que al principio Firebase cuesta un poco pillarlo, pero con esto ya tengo para hacer una implementación decente, gracias de nuevo!